# Deserializing nested JSON

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Need an extra pair of eyes to see what i am doing wrong here. Help appreciated.(including criticisms) I am quite new to Json so please go easy on me.

While just playing around with the BandsInTown API, i am finding it weird to deserialize this json data.

I am not sure whats the best way to paste a Json result here, so please click on the link below to see the data.

https://app.bandsintown.com/events/just_announced?location=San+Francisco%2C+CA&radius=75&per_page=15&authenticate=false

Here's what i am trying to do,

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await HttpManager.BitRequestManager.SendRequest(uri);
```

`var jsonMessage = await HttpManager.BitResponseManager.ReadResponse(response);`

```
Here's my models,

public class PopularEvents
    {
        [JsonProperty("data")]
        public Data Data;
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public List<Events> events { get; set; }
    }

    public class Events
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string artist_event_id { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string datetime { get; set; }
        public string formatted_datetime { get; set; }
        public string formatted_location { get; set; }
        public string ticket_url { get; set; }
        public string ticket_type { get; set; }
        public string ticket_status { get; set; }
        public string on_sale_datetime { get; set; }
        public string facebook_rsvp_url { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        //public List<Artist> artists { get; set; }
        //public Venue venue { get; set; }
        public string facebook_event_id { get; set; }
        public int rsvp_count { get; set; }
        public int? media_id { get; set; }
    }
var events = (List<PopularEvents>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonMessage, typeof(List<PopularEvents>));
```

When i do this, i get an error as shown below,

> A first chance exception of type
>   'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in
>   Newtonsoft.Json.DLL Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g.
>   {"name":"value"}) into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[BandsInTown.Models.PopularEvents]'
>   because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array
>   (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal
>   .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection
>   type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON
>   object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it
>   to deserialize from a JSON object.

What am i doing wrong here? essentially what i am trying to do is take the events as a list of objects and thats pretty much it.

Comment: Since that's a huge amount of data to debug and help you out with, check out http://json2csharp.com/ - Paste the JSON in there and look at what it spits out for you (it generates C# classes from JSON). `RootObject` is the top-level object (So you'd use JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>() )

Comment: Took that route first. Does not help.

Comment: Does not help, you mean it doesn't serialize properly with the generated classes?

Comment: In that case, this should help right? 

    public class PopularEvents
    {
        [JsonProperty("data")]
        public Data Data;
    }

    public class Data
    {
        [JsonProperty("events")]
        public List<Events> Events { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Yep, it's a good start

Comment: No luck there. There is something really weird about this. I did try all of this today. 

Its just with this json i have a problem. to get basic json data, everything works fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82448/discussion-between-golldy-and-rob).

Comment: The outer element doesn't seem to be a list, shouldn't it just be `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PopularEvents>(jsonMessage)`  instead of `List<PopularEvents>` ?

Comment: PS: you can skip the need for the outer root classes and get the Events list directly by doing something like: `List<Events> events = JObject.Parse(jsonMessage)["data"]["events"].ToObject<List<Events>>();`

Comment: I tried this exact thing earlier. So when i do this, i just get the events and not artists. I do not get the nested artists as it is always null.

Comment: Strange, the artist lists are part of an event, not of the root objects (pages are). Did a quick test, but by adding an Artist class and uncommenting the artists list, I got the objects filled completely

Answer (score 5, accepted):

working fine here:

```
var res = new HttpClient().GetAsync("https://app.bandsintown.com/events/just_announced?location=San+Francisco%2C+CA&radius=75&per_page=15&authenticate=false").Result;
var t = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PopularEvents>(new StreamReader(res.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result).ReadToEnd());
```

Basically the `json` is all about `PopularEvents` and not a `List<PopularEvents>` as mentioned by @Me.Name.

Answer (score 1):

Just tried this locally now, it's definitely working:

```
public class Artist
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string image_url { get; set; }
    public string thumb_url { get; set; }
    public string large_image_url { get; set; }
    public bool on_tour { get; set; }
    public string events_url { get; set; }
    public string sony_id { get; set; }
    public int tracker_count { get; set; }
    public bool verified { get; set; }
    public int media_id { get; set; }
}

public class Venue
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string region { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public double latitude { get; set; }
    public double longitude { get; set; }
}

public class Event
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string artist_event_id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string datetime { get; set; }
    public string formatted_datetime { get; set; }
    public string formatted_location { get; set; }
    public string ticket_url { get; set; }
    public string ticket_type { get; set; }
    public string ticket_status { get; set; }
    public string on_sale_datetime { get; set; }
    public string facebook_rsvp_url { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public List<Artist> artists { get; set; }
    public Venue venue { get; set; }
    public string facebook_event_id { get; set; }
    public int rsvp_count { get; set; }
    public int? media_id { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public List<Event> events { get; set; }
}

public class Pages
{
    public int current_page { get; set; }
    public int total_results { get; set; }
    public int results_per_page { get; set; }
    public string next_page_url { get; set; }
    public object previous_page_url { get; set; }
}

public class PopularEvents
{
    public Data data { get; set; }
    public Pages pages { get; set; }
}
```

Then calling:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PopularEvents>(json)
```

Deserializes without a problem.

Comment: Still no luck...

i did this on the classes you have in your answer. 

public async Task<PopularEvents> GetPopularEvents()
        {
            Uri uri = await UriHelper.GetPopularEventsNearby();

            HttpResponseMessage response = await HttpManager.BitRequestManager.SendRequest(uri);
            var jsonMessage = await HttpManager.BitResponseManager.ReadResponse(response);

            var events = (PopularEvents)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonMessage, typeof(PopularEvents));
            return events;
        }

Comment: @golldy What error do you get here? Can you also try it just by pasting in the JSON directly? (Maybe the API is not always returning the same properties, which you'll need to configure in Newtonsoft)

Comment: Suprisingly this worked for me,

var res = new HttpClient().GetAsync("https://app.bandsintown.com/events/just_announced?location=San+Francisco%2C+CA&radius=75&per_page=15&authenticate=false").Result;
            var t = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PopularEvents>(new StreamReader(res.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result).ReadToEnd());

Comment: @golldy Perhaps it was an issue with the stream not being complete..? Not sure

Answer (score 1):

Just change line from your code:

```
var events = (List<PopularEvents>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonMessage, typeof(List<PopularEvents>));
```

By the following:

```
var events = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PopularEvents>(json);
```

I've just checked it in code:

```
var res = new HttpClient().GetAsync("https://app.bandsintown.com/events/just_announced?location=San+Francisco%2C+CA&radius=75&per_page=15&authenticate=false").Result;
string json = new StreamReader(res.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result).ReadToEnd();
var events = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PopularEvents>(json);
```

And all works fine

It is because the root element of JSON is data and it is about PopularEvents classs, not about List< PopularEvents>